# How to do an initial batch import of CSV / MySQL data into neo4j database

Tags: database, import, converters, neo4j, graph-databases

I am considering replacing a MySQL database with a neo4j database. I am a complete beginner with neo4j and would like to know how to go about doing a batch insert of my current MySQL data into the neo4j database so i can experiment and begin to learn about neo4j.

the relational database consists of 4 tables: `Person`, `Organism`, `Story`, `Links`.
Links describes relationships between rows in the other 3 tables.

`Links`:
ID, FromTable, FromID, ToTable, ToID, LinkType

`Person`:
ID, property_2, property_1, etc ...

`Organism`:
ID, property_A, property_B, etc ....

`Story`:
ID, property_x, property_y

each ID field is an auto incrementing integer starting from 1 for each table

In case it is not obvious, a link between say person with ID 3 and a story with ID 42 would have a row in the Links table ID=autoincrement, FromTable=Person, FromID=3, ToTable=Story, ToID=42.
Even though I am using the terms 'from' and 'to' the actual links are not really 'directed' in practice.

I have looked at Michael Hunger's [batch-import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) but that seems to only work with a single table of nodes and one table of relationships, whereas I am looking to import three different types of nodes and one list of relationships between them.

I have got neo4j up and running, 
Any advice to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

I am not familiar with Java, though I do use Python and bash shell scripts.
After initial import, I will be using the RESTful interface with Javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on advice [in the git repo](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/issues/4). Using Michael Hunger's [batch-import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) it is possible to import multiple node types from the one .csv file.
To quote Michael:

> Just put them all into one nodes file, you can have any attribute not
>   having a value in a certain row, it will then just be skipped.

So the general approach i used was:

combine all the nodes tables into a new table called `nodes`:

1. Create a new table `nodes` with an auto incrementing `newID` field and a `type` field. the type field will record what table the node data came from
2. Add all the possible columns names from the 3 node tables allowing nulls.
3. `INSERT INTO nodes` the values from `Person`, then `Organism`, then `Story`, in addition to setting the `type` field to person, organism, or story. Leave any unrelated fields blank.

in another new table `rels` add the newly created `newID` indexes to the `Links` table based on a  sql `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO rels
SELECT  
    n1.newID AS fromNodeID, 
    n2.newID AS toNodeID,
    L.LinkType,
    L.ID
FROM 
    Links L
LEFT JOIN 
    nodes n1 
    ON 
    L.fromID = n1.ID 
    AND 
    L.fromType = n1.type
LEFT JOIN 
    nodes n2 
    ON 
    L.toID = n2.ID 
    AND 
    L.toType = n2.type;
```

Then export these two new tables `nodes` and `rels` as Tab seperated .csv files, and use them with batch-import:

```
$java -server -Xmx4G -jar target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv
```

Comment: cool stuff :) Here is an ETL related presentation by Max De Marzi http://www.slideshare.net/maxdemarzi/etl-into-neo4j

Answer (score 1):

As you say that you are happy working with python and shell scripts, you may also want to have a look at the command line tools which come with [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/), in particular `geoff`. This uses a flat file format I put together for holding graph data so in your instance, you would need to build a flat file from your source data and insert this into your graph database.

The file format and server plugin are documented [here](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff) and the py2neo module for the client application is [here](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/geoff/).

If anything is missing from the docs or you want more information about this then feel free to drop me an email

Nigel