# How to deal with null values for some properties with Neo4j batch-import?

Tags: java, import, neo4j, converters, graph-databases

I'm trying to import SQL data into my Neo4j graph database with Michael Hunger's batch-import which actually works very well.

To import more than one node type I do it like this: [How to do an initial batch import of CSV / MySQL data into neo4j database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505335/how-to-do-an-initial-batch-import-of-csv-mysql-data-into-neo4j-database)

Now my question is how to deal with null values for some properties? I don't want the batch-import to create node properties where the values are null.

If I leave the relevant entries blank the batch-import creates properties with a "0" as value. In addition, if I leave the last cell blank I'll get java.util.NoSuchElementException.
When the relevant entries contain the value "null" the batch-import creates node properties with value "null".

My CSV-Files are tab separated with UTF-8 encoding.

Thank you for your helpful response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned the latest git repo from https://github.com/jexp/batch-import and built the batch-import myself. The jar I used seemed to be out-of-date.
Now it works very well by just leaving the relevant entries blank.